# Setting selected item in UISegmentControl is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

Trying to set the selected side of a UISegmentControl, but nothing happens.

In my viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear this code will not select a segment?

```
[self.segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:[@1 integerValue]];
```

Nothing happens?

Comment: Have you logged self.segmentedControl to see if it's nil?

Comment: BTW - why not simply pass `1` instead of `[@1 integerValue]`?

Comment: If it is nil, then make sure the outlets are connected correctly (assuming you're using Storyboards or InterfaceBuilder).

Comment: Try from -(void)awakeFromNib ?

Comment: It is NOT nil. The segmentControl exists during execution. @rmaddy Its a place holder I have code that returns the one I want to select dynamic. I just hardcoded it this way to be sure it wasn't my other method.

Comment: @lead_the_zeppelin tried it and the same result?

Comment: Which segment is being highlighted? The segmented control starts counting at 0, so this should highlight the second segment, correct?

Comment: The fact that "it exists during execution", if by that you mean its action method works, doesn't mean the IBOutlet is connected. The outlet could be nil, but the object exists and is functional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the UISegmentControl from the Storyboard and added it programmatically and it works now. Very weird.

```
self.segControl.frame = CGRectMake(35, 100, 200, 50);
self.segControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
self.segControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;

[self.view addSubview:self.segControl];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use code for adding and setting selected tab in UISegmentControl

```
 NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Top Twenty", @"Dow thirty", @"Favorite", nil];
    segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(15, 80, 300, 30);
    segmentedControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(MySegmentControlAction:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0; //**this line represent selected tab**
    [self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];
```